# How to update our branch from main & stash files?

Tags: git, github

1. how to update our local branch from main
2. How to stash the changes ?

I am getting these errors while trying to update my branch from main.

I don't want to merge into main, I want to update my local branch (keeping my changes and getting new changes from main).

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You stash them with `git stash` (please don't post pictures of text). You unstash them with `git stash pop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first do `commit` before runing `pull` or `rebase`.

If your work is not ready to commit, you can still do a temporary commit and `pull rebase` so that your commit becomes the latest and `reset` your `HEAD` to the previous commit, removing the temporary commit and leaving your changes in the working copy.

Something like this depending on the situation:

```
git commit -a -m 'temporary commit'
git pull --rebase
git reset HEAD~1
```

Comment: how to commit  ?

Answer (score 0):

You could stash the modified files first before making `pull` or `rebase`.

By running `git stash`, Git will save the working directory and index state for latterly applying back to your working area. After running `git stash`, all the modified files would be saved and back to the state before the modification has made, and you could check the stashed items by running `git stash list` and `git stash show`, as the following example,

```bash
$ git status                                                                                                                                                              
On branch main
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   example.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

$ git stash                                                                                                                                                               
Saved working directory and index state WIP on main: e856771 add file # the latest commit (HEAD) in your working branch

$ git stash list                                                                                                                                                         
stash@{0}: WIP on main: e856771 add file

$ git stash show stash@{0}                                                                                                                                                
 example.txt | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

After stashing the dirty working directory, you would be able to make `git pull` from the remote branch.

The last step is restoring the temporary stashed files back to your working directory, which can be achieved by running `git stash apply`,

```bash
$ git stash apply stash@\{0\}                                                                                                                                              
On branch main
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   example.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Alternatively, if the changes you want to restore is exactly the one you just stashed, you also could use `git stash pop` to pop out the latest stashed changes in the working directory. Noted that `git stash drop` would also remove it from your stash entries, but `git stash apply` wouldn't do that.

```bash
$ git stash pop                                                                                                                                                            
On branch main
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   example.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (f28a4a5937601f0b7c23c2fb42444a08a89d7042)
```